# Зачем создавать дополнительную переменную в первом цикле?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Можно ли обойтись без переменной `str`,объявленной во внешнем цикле и напрямую сравнивать `arr[i]` с `result[i]`?

У меня есть только одно соображение по этому поводу,что бы хранить начало внешнего цикла в переменной `str`,на случай расширения или внесение изменений в функцию.Потому как в противном случае после полного прохода внешнего цикла,начало нигде уже не сохранится.Но может быть я ошибаюсь? Пусть `arr` – массив строк.

Напишите функцию `unique(arr)`, которая возвращает массив, содержащий только уникальные элементы `arr` К примеру,что то бы выводился массив строк:  кришна, харе, 8-().

```js
function unique(arr) {
  var result = [];

  nextInput:
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var str = arr[i]; // для каждого элемента
      for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) { // ищем, был ли он уже?
        if (result[j] == str) continue nextInput; // если да, то следующий
      }
      result.push(str);
    }

  return result;
}

var strings = ["кришна", "кришна", "харе", "харе",
  "харе", "харе", "кришна", "кришна", "8-()"
];

console.log(unique(strings)); // кришна, харе, 8-()
```

Comment: Быть может, это была попытка оптимизации на коленке? Ну, операция извлечения элемента из массива, вероятно, не мгновенная...

Comment: По коду, всё вот это вот, по хорошему, переписать бы в Set/HashSet. И скорость возрастёт куда значительнее. (И да, метка nextInput точно на том месте? По мне, следуя логике кода, разумно было бы, если бы она шла после первого for(;;), хотя... это ж js...)

Comment: Да, можно. Чо думать то.

Comment: В js есть continue на метку? Как бы это забыть?

Comment: Странно почему,дубликат? По ссылке перешел.. да там то же задание.. но решение через объект.. я решал так.. но интересуют нюансы именно медленного решения  данного примера

Answer (score 2):

Можно немножко проще сделать с помощью [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function unique(arr) {
  return arr.filter((curr, index, self) => self.indexOf(curr) === index);
}

const strings = ["кришна", "кришна", "харе", "харе",
  "харе", "харе", "кришна", "кришна", "8-()"
];

console.log(unique(strings));
```

A если будут приставать с вычислительной сложностью, можно спрятать всё:

```js
function unique(arr) {
 return Array.from(new Set(arr));
}

const strings = ["кришна", "кришна", "харе", "харе",
  "харе", "харе", "кришна", "кришна", "8-()"
];

console.log(unique(strings));
```

Подробнее: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Так себе решение - О(n^2) же